# Tageting a specific menu link with nav_menu_css_class

Tags: menus

The following is my `top-menu` when rendered on page...

```
<ul id="top-menu" class="menu">
...
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://localhost:8082/demo/">Demo</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-39"><a href="http://google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

...what should my `if($item)` condition be to concatenate `my_custom_class` to `.menu-item-39`?

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'my_nav_special_class' , 10 , 2);
function my_nav_special_class($classes, $item){
    if($item){ //what should this condition be?
        $classes[] = 'my_custom_class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Or should I be going about a better filter to process this same request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to go about this: in menu administration, add your custom class directly to the menu item. To enable this, go to Screen Options at the top of the menu editing screen and check the "CSS Classes" box under "Show advanced menu properties."

Once you check that box, you'll have a new "CSS Classes (optional)" text input box for each menu item, and you can add it there.

Comment: https://www.lockedowndesign.com/add-css-classes-to-menu-items-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this process earlier.  This only adds a custom class to the li element.  I need to add a custom class name, provided by another plugin, to the anchor link that is the child within that li element.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I thought about what you said again because its making me think about how I'm going about this.  It's much each to create a pop-up in wordpress, off of a custom class that is associated to a li element, then trying to force the same process by placing a custom class directly on a anchor link.  As a result I found a plugin that places the custom class on an li element for me, in addition to your instructions of enabling 'CSS Classes'  Thanks!

Comment: If you did want to change a class of a different element, the solution would be to create a custom walker. They are a little tricky to begin with but once you've played with them a bit they can make the markup exactly what you want it to be. I use them to add the right classes to make things into Foundation dropdown menus.